# ASP.NET website still looking for old name of renamed referenced assembly

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, assemblies, reference, projects-and-solutions

I have a solution with a website and a class library. I have renamed the class library project from Insight_WebControls to Insight.WebControls. I have also renamed the assembly it produces in its properties.

I have removed from the website's references the old class library and added the new.

However, when I try to build the website, I get the error 'Could not load file or assembly 'Insight_WebControls' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.' There is a dll called 'Insight.WebControls' in the bin folder.

Clearly some part of the website is still looking for the old filename. Can anyone tell me how to point it to Insight.WebControls.dll instead?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a couple of shots in the dark:

Have you looked inside the web.config to see if there is any reference to the old file name in there?

If that turns up a blank then try opening up the project file for the web site and do a similar search.

Comment: You are a genius, that's exactly what it was. The class library was a load of web controls, so of course the assembly name was referred to in web.config. Thank you very kindly.